# Facebook Graph API returns 400 on first request, 200 on second, both requests are the same

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post to facebook via java, and it works, but only on the second POST request. The first always returns a HTTP 400, while the second works fine.

```
final URL url = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed" + urlParameters);
            String facebookPostUrl = url.toString();
            Client client = Client.create();
            WebResource facebookPost = client.resource(facebookPostUrl);
            ClientResponse response = facebookPost.get(ClientResponse.class);
            response.close();
```

The parameters I'm passing in are correct. If I copy the request into a browser it works just fine.

I should note that I'm performing a GET request with ClientResponse, and signalling to FB that it is a post by using the &method=POST in the URL.

The 400 response : 
     response-code GET https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=TOKEN&link=http%3A%2F%2Fbit.ly%2F1dHkdAV&method=post&caption=gigj returned a response status of 400 Bad Request

I removed the access token for privacy.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please post the entire 400 response, including headers and body.

Comment: Added it. I really can't see why it fails on the first attempt then succeeds on the second, when the request isn't changing.

Comment: No response body on the 400? And just to be clear, since you didn't post complete code, you're reissuing the exact same request successfully from the exact same code?

Comment: Yup, no body.! It's really annoying me, doesn't make sense at all. If I try 
ClientResponse response = facebookPost.get(ClientResponse.class);
ClientResponse response2 = facebookPost.get(ClientResponse.class);

response2 succeeds, while response fails. It makes no sense!

Comment: That's not exactly the same request; you're reusing the `WebResource` object. Debug the code and compare the state of `facebookPost` before the first request to the state between requests.

Comment: Hmm, but even if I just have one WebResource object and one ClientResponse.get call, it always fails on the first run, then even if I stop the program and restart it, it will succeed the second time.

Comment: What about if you wait several minutes and then try the call in the browser? You say that it works, but is that because you always try it after the first "warmup" failure in Java?

Comment: I don't see how that changes my problem? I know I'm submitting a valid request because facebook accepts it, the problem is that they only accept it on the 2nd try!

Comment: Right, but don't always assume the other endpoint is behaving correctly. I'm trying to figure out whether Facebook is erroneously returning a 400 when it's not warmed up.

Comment: Yeah good call, I'll send a request and let it sit for a while, then see if it works.

Comment: Aaand it doesn't seem to make a difference :/